# WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined - netlify build

Tags: reactjs, build, gatsby

**I am getting an error building my project on netlify (WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined). In develop works fine!**

I saw that is possible to solve this problem with JSDOM but i have tried and i couldn't make it right.

```
    import React from "react";
    import "../css/DarkMode.css";
    
    const DarkMode = () => {
      let clickedClass = "clicked";
      const body = document.body;
      const lightTheme = "light";
      const darkTheme = "dark";
      let theme;
    
      if (localStorage) {
        theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
      }
    
      if (theme === lightTheme || theme === darkTheme) {
        body.classList.add(theme);
      } else {
        body.classList.add(lightTheme);
      }
    
      const switchTheme = (e) => {
        if (theme === darkTheme) {
          body.classList.replace(darkTheme, lightTheme);
          e.target.classList.remove(clickedClass);
          localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
          theme = lightTheme;
        } else {
          body.classList.replace(lightTheme, darkTheme);
          e.target.classList.add(clickedClass);
          localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
          theme = darkTheme;
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <button
          className={theme === "dark" ? clickedClass : ""}
          id="darkMode"
          className={"btnDarkMode"}
          onClick={(e) => switchTheme(e)}
        ></button>
      );
    };
    
    export default DarkMode;
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending [@mirik999's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603019/5585371):

It's not about [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) *per se*. As it has been said, with React, you are creating and manipulating a virtual DOM (vDOM), and with your snippet, you are pointing directly to the real DOM (`document.body` and so on). In addition, these actions decreases drastically the performance of the code/application since they have a huge cost by the browser, that's why React is so fast (among other things).

Manipulating the real DOM in a React application may cause severe caveats and warnings, potentially blocking the [hydration of React](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/) (the refreshing/re-rendering new content-on-demand).

The fact that your code works under `gatsby develop` and not in `gatsby build` is, summarizing, because `gatsby develop` is handled by the browser, [where there are global objects (such as `window` or `document`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/). `gatsby build` id compiled in the Node server, where obviously there's no `window` or `document` because they are not even created yet.

The easy workaround is to wrap your code (where you are using global objects) in this condition:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) { // or typeof document !== 'undefined'
  // your code that uses global objects here
}
```

But as I said, it may block the hydration of React.

To add theming in Gatsby, you have a bunch of options like using plugins ([`gatsby-plugin-dark-mode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/)) or use a React-based approach.

Useful resources:

- https://victorzhou.com/blog/dark-mode-gatsby/
- https://dev.to/hasone/how-to-add-dark-mode-in-gatsby-react-project-jml

Comment: thanks man! I have already tried to use gatsby-plugin-dark-mode but it have a feature that a i dont like, if you have darkmode by default on your bowser it automatically change the page to darkmode and i don't like that i want to have a button to turn on and off, but thanks. i will try a React-base approach for sure. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You want to realize theme switching totally wrong.

1. React uses Virtual DOM not a real dom. ( Virtual DOM is an Object version of HTML tree )
   that is the reason why document is not defined before page init. If you want to get document it will be best practice to use it in `useEffect()` hook. ( after page init )
2. In your case you have a lot of choice to realize multi theming ,  I would recommend to use styled-components